# Is this a valid formula for the argument function?

Tags: complex-analysis

I originally came up with this formula while working on a coding project, and realized that it described the properties of the argument function.

$$\operatorname{Arg}(z) = \operatorname{sgn}( \operatorname{Re}(z) )\arccos( \operatorname{Im}(z) / \lvert z\rvert ) ,\quad\text{for all $z \ne 0$.}$$

Both $\operatorname{Arg}$ and the expression I've found have the same domain, $\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$ and output $(-\pi, \pi]$ and so I wonder if there exists some proof for this equality, more rigorous than my trial and error.

Comment: Draw a right-angled triangle from $0$ to $z \in \mathbb{C}$ in the Argand diagram, with legs on the real and imaginary axes. Note that the hypotenuse then has length $|z|$.

Comment: For some reason my comment disappeared on migration: "You can prove it yourself: compute the cosine of the angle you have proposed (easy since cosine is an even function), and the sine (where you will have to do some case distinctions depending on whether the arccosine, normalised as you have done, is acute or obtuse)."